# Trouble installing Karma via npm

Tags: node.js, karma-runner

I'm having trouble installing Karma via npm.

My Mac: OS X 10.9.2 (Darwin 13.1.0)
My version of node is: v0.10.26
My version of npm is: v1.4.3

```
sudo npm install -g karma

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/di

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/q

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/log4js

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/useragent

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/di

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/q

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/log4js

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/useragent

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect

npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/recursive-readdir/0.0.2

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/0.2.0

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.16

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utile

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.1.15

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/semver

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/batch/0.5.0

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.6

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.1

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/recursive-readdir/0.0.2

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.4

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.1

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.2.0

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uid2/0.0.3

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.1.0

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-body/1.1.2

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator/0.3.0

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/multiparty/2.2.0

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/0.2.0

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.16

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/utile

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.1.15

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/i

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/batch/0.5.0

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.6

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.1

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.1

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.4

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/isarray/0.0.1

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.1.0

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.2.0

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ws

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uid2/0.0.3

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-body/1.1.2



> fsevents@0.2.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents

> node-gyp rebuild



  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node: Finished

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/multiparty/2.2.0

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator/0.3.0

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/i

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/isarray/0.0.1

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ws

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/options

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-counter

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/options

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-counter



> ws@0.4.31 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws

> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)



  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node: Finished

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node: Finished

karma@0.12.6 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma

├── di@0.0.1

├── graceful-fs@2.0.3

├── rimraf@2.2.6

├── colors@0.6.2

├── mime@1.2.11

├── q@0.9.7

├── glob@3.2.9 (inherits@2.0.1)

├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.5.0)

├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.8)

├── lodash@2.4.1

├── source-map@0.1.33 (amdefine@0.1.0)

├── useragent@2.0.8 (lru-cache@2.2.4)

├── log4js@0.6.13 (semver@1.1.4, async@0.1.15, readable-stream@1.0.26-4)

├── http-proxy@0.10.4 (pkginfo@0.3.0, utile@0.2.1)

├── connect@2.12.0 (uid2@0.0.3, methods@0.1.0, debug@0.8.0, cookie-signature@1.0.1, pause@0.0.1, fresh@0.2.0, qs@0.6.6, bytes@0.2.1, buffer-crc32@0.2.1, raw-body@1.1.2, batch@0.5.0, cookie@0.1.0, negotiator@0.3.0, send@0.1.4, multiparty@2.2.0)

├── chokidar@0.8.2 (recursive-readdir@0.0.2, fsevents@0.2.0)

└── socket.io@0.9.16 (base64id@0.1.0, policyfile@0.0.4, redis@0.7.3, socket.io-client@0.9.16)
```

Comment: That output seems to indicate that it installed just fine..?

Comment: What evidence do you have that it isn't working?

Comment: I agree it's sitting there ok. However, when I do karma --version i get... -bash: karma: command not found.

Comment: > fsevents@0.2.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents

> node-gyp rebuild

Comment: > ws@0.4.31 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws

> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

Comment: I'm not sure if fsevents & socket.io installed correctly.

Comment: I've also tried:npm install -g node-gyp
# npm install -g socket.io

Answer (score 5):

`sudo npm install -g karma-cli`

There's a separate module for the CLI tool, sadly.

Comment: Twats! They could of mentioned that on https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma. Anyway, thanks for that it worked. I've been dicking around for an hour trying to get this to work.