# node-gyp rebuild 2 error when installing Karma

Tags: node.js, karma-runner

I am trying to install Karma onto OSX v10.9.3.

I open up the terminal and enter `npm install -g karma`.  When I do this, I get the following output:

```
mc-s089979% npm install -g karma

> fsevents@0.2.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node: Finished

> ws@0.4.31 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node: Finished
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node: Finished
karma@0.12.16 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma
├── di@0.0.1
├── graceful-fs@2.0.3
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── colors@0.6.2
├── mime@1.2.11
├── q@0.9.7
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.5.0)
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
├── source-map@0.1.33 (amdefine@0.1.0)
├── glob@3.2.11 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0)
├── lodash@2.4.1
├── useragent@2.0.8 (lru-cache@2.2.4)
├── log4js@0.6.14 (semver@1.1.4, async@0.1.15, readable-stream@1.0.27-1)
├── http-proxy@0.10.4 (pkginfo@0.3.0, utile@0.2.1)
├── chokidar@0.8.2 (recursive-readdir@0.0.2, fsevents@0.2.0)
├── connect@2.12.0 (uid2@0.0.3, methods@0.1.0, cookie-signature@1.0.1, debug@0.8.1, pause@0.0.1, fresh@0.2.0, bytes@0.2.1, qs@0.6.6, raw-body@1.1.2, buffer-crc32@0.2.1, batch@0.5.0, cookie@0.1.0, negotiator@0.3.0, send@0.1.4, multiparty@2.2.0)
└── socket.io@0.9.17 (base64id@0.1.0, policyfile@0.0.4, redis@0.7.3, socket.io-client@0.9.16)
```

If I then try to execute karma by typing `karma` in the terminal, I get `command not found: karma` which suggests that it hasn't been installed.  Looking in the output above, there is an error:  `(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)`.  I've found builderror.log in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/builderror.log`, however, it is empty.  `find` couldn't find any other builderror.log files.  Do you know where else to look?

I've tried:

- `npm update`
- `npm install karma`
- `sudo npm install karma`
- `sudo npm install -g karma`

What else should I try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that it was installing.  I didn't think it was because running karma from the command line didn't work.  However, in order to run it from the command line you need to install karma-cli:  `npm install -g karma-cli`

Thanks to @peter-lyons for this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23044629/211560

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .slugignore file:

```
       /node_modules/grunt-karma/
       /node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/
       /node_modules/karma/
       /node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher/
       /node_modules/karma-mocha/
       /node_modules/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor/
```